# gettext from C++Builder (i18n)

Tags: localization, c++builder, gettext, iconv, intl

I need to call gettext from C++ code for localization, and I'm using C++Builder as the IDE. I need to know how I can fetch libintl and libiconv dlls/libs for C++Builder.

Is there any other way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1):

[GNU Gettext for Delphi and C++ Builder](http://dxgettext.po.dk/)